# Grabbing web element on the picture with cypress. The flex element seems to be hiding everything. I need help to grab the text input area

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a problem grabbing this input area with cypress automation.

[image]

I have tried:

```
cy.get('#license_number_plate')
// and
cy.contains('License plate number')
```

Comment: You are trying to get license_number_plate and the element is license_plate_number. Try `cy.get('[id="license_plate_number"]')`

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried virtually everything.

Comment: @ItsNotAndy that also works.

Comment: What message are you getting ? Element is hidden from the DOM ?

Comment: You should probably include your test code in case so we can see why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the text of the aria-label

```js
it('types in a licence plate', () => {
  cy.visit('https://www.cars.com/sell/');
  cy.get('[aria-label="License plate number"]')
    .focus()
    .type('abc123')
})
```

[image]

Comment: No luck here as well

Comment: What are you doing wrong? It works, see above.